# Mysql count on ORDERBY not working with Join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables "coin_review" and "un_user_follower",And i want to fetch "Top Reviewer"(except me(123),And whose Most Review exist,with his follower)
Here is my table "coin_review"

```
id          Review              wallet_address      
1           Lorem Ipsum1        123 
2           Lorem Ipsum2        1234
3           Lorem Ipsum3        1234
4           Lorem Ipsum4        12345
```

...

Here is my table "un_user_follower"

```
id          from_wallet_address         to_wallet_address       
1           1234                            11111       
2           1234                            12254
3           123                             25141
4           12345                           14144
5           12345                           14798
...
```

Now as result i want to Get Top Reviewer (Whose most record exist) and Total number of his follower
For example i want following output as result

```
id          wallet_address          TotalReview         TotalFollowers
1           1234                        2                   2
2           12345                       1                   1
```

For this i tried with following query

```
SELECT cr.id,COUNT(cr.Review) as Total,COUNT(usf.to_wallet_address)
FROM coin_review cr
JOIN un_user_follower usf
ON usf.to_wallet_address=cr.wallet_address
WHERE cr.wallet_address!='123'
GROUP BY cr.Review
ORDER BY Total ASC
```

But i am getting following errror,How can i solve this ?Where i am wrong ?

```
SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'Uni_back.cr.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
```

Comment: If `cr.Review` is unique (by according unique index) then use `GROUP BY cr.id, cr.Review`. If not then use `SELECT MIN(cr.id) AS id, ...`. *Where i am wrong ?* Imagine that `cr.Review` is not unique, and 2 rows with the same value have different `cr.id` values. What value from these 2 ones must be returned in single row for this `Review`? server doesn't know, and hence it produces an error.

Comment: @Akina: can you write exact query so i can check and implement in my side

Comment: Provide CREATE TABLE scripts for both tables primarily (edit your question text). Also explain where the output value for `TotalFollowers` is obtained from... The amount of non-NULL `to_wallet_address values`?

Comment: Full join (use a trick as Mysql doesn't support full joins) grouped and filtered original tables.

Comment: @Serg: Then what is solution for this ? How can i get Most Reviewers ?

Comment: Reread the question, no FULL JOIN needed. Just LEFT JOIN. See the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top two reviewers and their followers count.
First group tables then LEFT JOIN.

```
SELECT cr.wallet_address, cr.TotalReview, coalesce(fl.TotalFollowers,0) TotalFollowers
FROM (
  SELECT wallet_address, COUNT(Review) as TotalReview
  FROM coin_review 
  WHERE wallet_address!='123'
  GROUP BY wallet_address
  ORDER BY COUNT(Review) DESC
  LIMIT 2 
)  cr
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT from_wallet_address,  COUNT(to_wallet_address) TotalFollowers
  FROM  un_user_follower
  WHERE from_wallet_address!='123'
  GROUP BY from_wallet_address
) fl ON cr.wallet_address = fl.from_wallet_address
ORDER BY cr.TotalReview ASC
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=91bd14bc68acb2ee72b0ab1c792e4a43)

returns

```
wallet_address  TotalReview TotalFollowers
12345   1   2
1234    2   2
```

Comment: Wouldn't this result in `wallet_adress` **12345** `total_followers` **2**? Either OP's desired result is wrong, or I don't understand the logic.

Comment: @Michel , yes it will return total_followers = 2 for wallet_adress 12345. I followed the wording "Total number of his follower "

Comment: I was just asking for an explanation on the **1** when you posted the answer. Suppose OP made a typo.

Comment: @Serg: its working but i want "0" in "TotalFollowers" instead of "NULL"

Comment: Added the fiddle

Comment: `coalesce(fl.TotalFollowers,0)`